# opencv cannot load jp2 image files

Tags: c++, opencv, load, jpeg2000

I am using opencv 2.3.1 on Debian. The following code fails to load a given jpeg 2000 file.

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    IplImage* img_temp = cvLoadImage("delmeg.jp2", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
    //IplImage* img_temp = cvLoadImage("delmec.jp2");
    if(img_temp == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't load the image.." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::Mat img(img_temp);

    if (img_temp != NULL){
        cvReleaseImage(&img_temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used the following command to compile it:

```
g++ -Wall -g -I /usr/include/ testopencv2x.cpp -o testopencv2x -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

Anybody know what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about 2.3.1, but here is what the [documentation says about 2.4.3](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#explanation):

> **Note**: OpenCV offers support for the image formats Windows bitmap (bmp), portable image formats (pbm, pgm, ppm) and Sun raster (sr, ras). **With help of plugins (you need to specify to use them if you build yourself the library**, nevertheless in the packages we ship present by default) you may also load image formats like JPEG (jpeg, jpg, jpe), **JPEG 2000** (jp2 - codenamed in the CMake as Jasper), TIFF files (tiff, tif) and portable network graphics (png). Furthermore, OpenEXR is also a possibility.

So make sure you build OpenCV to support this format.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the documentatoin, so perhaps I don't understand it properly. In this context, I have also tried compiling OpenCV (in Windows 7) by specifying jasper (the jpeg2000 library) in cmake to be built in. In that case also I am not able to read the jp2 files (same source code as I have listed).

Comment: Furthermore, I have jasper libs installed on my Debian machines: libjasper-dev and libjasper1:i386

Comment: Make sure CMake can see them. Before issuing `make` you should be able to see if cmake was able to find the libraries on your system to support this type.

Comment: I thought OpenCV source code came with jasper source code (when I compiled in Windows). When I configure cmake, I confirmed that it is going to build JPEG 2000 build ver 1.900.1. Besides, Linux already appears to have jasper libraries installed. So I seem to be all set for this. I was wondering whether you are able to load a jp2 file in your setup, or if I can trouble you to try my code example.

Comment: Upload your jp2 file somewhere and let me try it.

Comment: I was trying to form an image to upload for your test and I discovered that I am actually able to load a jp2 file. This was done on an example image (the airplane.jpg that comes with opencv, converted to jp2). Then I tried with my own image that I am working with again, it failed. Then I converted that image to a jp2 image again (using the convert command in Linux) and lo and behold I was able to read the newly converted image. So it looks like there is either a problem with the original jp2 image encoding, or memory allocation problem. I will update here with what I find out. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, just found out that the jp2 files I was working with do not appear to be properly formed. Now, geeqie in Linux reads those same files fine, irfanviewer in Windows does too, only cvLoadImage cannot load them. As I mentioned earlier, converting those jp2 files to jp2 files using imagemagic appears to produce sane jp2 files that cvLoadImage is able to read.Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: No problem, feel free to up vote my answer if it helped or select it as the official problem solver by clicking on the checkbox near it. Good luck.

Comment: Sure, I will mark it as the solution since it is technically correct. Besides, the comments should give the whole picture to any future online wanderer.