# Why does OpenCV imread() return grayscale images, despite color flag?

Tags: python, opencv, imread

I'm reading an [jp2 file](https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/lusat/dop/dop_jp2_f10/) using openCV's `imread()`.
The image loads, but it's always grayscale.

I saw in the documentation that some [IMREAD_FLAGS](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80aeddd67043ed0df14f9d9a4e66d2b0708) could cause this and I also know that cv2 may change the channel order to BGR.

However, I believe none of these reasons are the issue here. I imported the image with different IMREAD_FLAGS and saved copies like this:

```py
image = cv2.imread("mypath.jp2", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # change flag here
cv2.imwrite("IMREAD_UNCHANGED.png", image) # change file name accordingly
```

I also converted the image to RGB using `cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`. The resulting image sizes are different, but the result are always a grayscale image:

[image]

Also, I'm certain these images have color, because when opening it with Pillow it looks like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you encountered a similar problem with any other image formats?

Comment: I looks like openCV may need to be compiled with a plugin or flag for .jp2 support (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733747/opencv-cannot-load-jp2-image-files) and (https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2021/08/05/python-en-opencv-convert-jp2-png-jpeg/).  Not sure if your python wrapper would have this or not.  You could also try `cv.IMREAD_COLOR` or `cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just tried a .jpg and it has colors as expected.

Comment: @Pete I tried `IMREAD_COLOR` (upper left) and also many other flags without any success. Could you explain how to compile with a plugin. It's not clear to me how this is done. `os.environ['OPENCV_IO_ENABLE_JASPER'] = 'true'` didn't change anything

Comment: I've never done it.  I'd switch to a more common format if possible, otherwise you might be headed down a nasty rabbit hole trying to get this format to work for you.  You may be able to find another library that does work well with `.jp2` and convert them to something else.

Comment: Try using `Pillow` instead of OpenCV, at least to convert the images (though I'd recommend using `Pillow` any time you do image processing - it's very intuitive). It produces a coloured image (though it's quite an unsaturated image anyway).

Comment: `image = Image.open("mypath.jp2") image.save("PILLOW.png")` indeed works. Worst case, I'll use Pillow. Although it takes 4x longer to load and save as compared to cv2...

Comment: I have opened one of the jp2 images that you link (dop10rgbi_32_280_5652_1_nw_2021.jp2) in several tools on my Mac and it looks to be gray with an alpha channel. There may be some color but it is faint if at all.  So post an actual example that you think has lots of color to it and identify what tool you use to view it in color.

Comment: The files may have confusing data in the header according to Exiftool. It says it has 4 components (channels?, RGBA) but has colorspace gray.

Comment: @fmw42 And there is a second, single channel image reported by `exiftool` afterwards...

Comment: @Mark Setchell.  I only see one file using exiftool.  What was your command?

Comment: @fmw42 I edited the question and included a portion of the image that I saved with Pillow

Comment: `@Michael S` Please link to the original image so we can check with Exiftool. My guess is that the JP2 header has confusing values and some tools read it as grayscale and others as color.  I have posted this question to Imagemagick forum in hopes that one of the developers can examine it in more detail and see why Imagemagick sees it as grayscale.

Comment: You can use [this one](https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/lusat/dop/dop_jp2_f10/dop10rgbi_32_284_5658_1_nw_2021.jp2) as example

Comment: Is that the same as you opened in Pillow? It does not match the color image you just posted!

Comment: FYI: Photoshop opens it as grayscale also.

Comment: @fmw42 I didn't use any flags with `exiftool`. It showed `Number of components=4` and `Bits per component=8`, but then `Samples per pixel=1`. I've never seen that before, but I've rarely interacted with JP2 images.

Answer (score 3):

When I use `cv.imread(path)` (OpenCV 4.7.0 on Windows), it gives me **three channels**, not grayscale. I didn't look to check if OpenCV removed any color information.

It does complain if I ask for `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`:

> [ERROR:0@171.019] global grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp:410 cv::`anonymous-namespace'::decodeGrayscaleData OpenJPEG2000: unsupported conversion from 4 components to 4 for Grayscale image decoding

The same error happens for `cv.imreadmulti(path, flags=cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` which is usually the right choice for multi-plane image formats (TIFF can be like that). Without the flag, it just returns one layer of 3-channel data.

So there's potential for a bug report. If you want to file it, do it on [OpenCV's github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues).

PIL reads it as "RGBA". There is no transparency there, it's just a 4th channel.

The file name contains "rgbi", which makes me suspect it's a multi-layer file, or at least the fourth channel contains another color layer, not "transparency".

If you convert from PIL Image to numpy array, at least you can get all the channels and their data.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(path)
im = np.asarray(im)
```

You could also use `imageio`. It warns about the image being huge, but it does load the whole thing. It's a complex library, so check the docs for recommended ways to read such files.

```
import imageio

im = imageio.read(path)
im.get_data(0) # (10000, 10000, 4)
```

Comment: I suspect (guess?) that the 4th channel is an IR channel.

Comment: IR would make a lot of sense for [estimating vegetation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index). metadata linked with the image downloads confirms, "near infrared"

Answer (score -1):

Docs say there are some modification flags for the *cv2 imread* function:

```
cv2.IMREAD_COLOR – It specifies to load a color image. Any transparency of image will be neglected. It is the default flag. Alternatively, we can pass integer value 1 for this flag.

cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE – It specifies to load an image in grayscale mode. Alternatively, we can pass integer value 0 for this flag. 

cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED – It specifies to load an image as such including alpha channel. Alternatively, we can pass integer value -1 for this flag.
```

See the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80) for full enum list.

So, if you face a problem with reading an image in the format you expect, you could try:

```py
cv2.imread(img_path, -1)
cv2.imread(img_path, 0)
```

or, in my case, I've solved this issue with

```py
cv2.imread(img_path, 3)
```

**[UPD]**
As Mark Setchell rightly corrected me, it is better to use constant names. So I've updated my answer with a neater and more readable way to do the trick:

```py
cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  
cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  
# and
cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
```

Comment: No, you should never use avoidable manifest constants. The developers have designed readable, portable, maintainable constant names for you and you should prefer those to unintelligible bare numbers.

Comment: are you just posting a generic answer or do you mean to say that the right flag to imread() would actually read the file correctly? with what version of opencv? back then (in April) , imshow() was unable to do it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, as I said, I've posted the solution that helped me with exactly the same problem. 
4.7.0 was releases at December of 2022. So yes, in April imshow() was able to do it. See details [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56)
UPD. btw, my current version of opencv is 4.5.4. Released in October of 2021.